# How I compact WAL files?

Tags: postgresql, backup, windows, log, write-ahead-logging

I like compact WAL files. Actually I do:

```
archive_command = 'cp "%p"C:\\%f"'
```

What is the best way to do it?

Comment: Can you add more details about what you are talking about?  As it stands this is pretty unclear.

Comment: I'm doing an incremental backup with wal files. I'm copying the files generated in pg_xlog in another directory. But I would like to store them compressed. Thanks @MaxVernon.

Comment: Linux, Windows, some other OS ?

Comment: Sorry, OS is Windows.

Comment: So, you just want to "zip" them up, then?

Comment: Yes! That's it :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Going by your other questions, it sounds like you have a short `archive_timeout` so your WAL archives are mostly empty, but are still the full pre-allocated 16MB file.

On most platforms you just gzip them, e.g.

```
archive_command = 'gzip -c < "%p" > /archive/path/%f"'
```

On Windows this won't work natively due to the lack of the `gzip` command. You'll need to install a compression utility that's usable from the command line, since the Windows zip support isn't directly usable from the commandline.

I suggest installing [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/download.html), then using it in your `archive_command`, with something like (untested):

```
archive_command = '%PROGRAMFILES%\7zip\7z.exe a "C:\\TheWALArchive\%f" "%p"'
```

Note that your `restore_command` will need a corresponding decompression step.

Comment: @Marcos That command doesn't make sense. See the one I wrote above and the documentation for restore_command

Comment: I use `'"C:\\Program Files\\7-Zip\\7z.exe" a "archivedir\\%f" "%p"'`. The files is compress. 
Do you think it makes sense to compress the files?
About `restore_command` I'm building solution. Thanks!

Comment: @Marcos Yes, compressing WAL archives makes a lot of sense. Especially if you have an archive_timeout set since then they will be mostly zeroes and compress extremely well.

Comment: @CraigRinger I'm curious. Is there any benefit/drawback to storing all the WAL files in a single 7zip archive?  Note also that compression from 7z is substantially better than gzip, so it's worth considering on unix too. Also, you need to prefix `%p` with a `.` if you don't want to copy the full path to the WAL file.   Incorporating these sugestions: `archive_command = '%PROGRAMFILES%\7zip\7z.exe a "C:\\TheWALArchive\wal_archive" ".%p"'`. Does that make sense?

Comment: I wouldn't want to for reasons of rotation and ease of incremental copying/archiving myself.