# WAL files management

Tags: postgresql, replication, postgresql-12, write-ahead-logging

I want to have advice about WAL management. I am expecting a large numbers of wal files (the database is very large and it has like 30 - 40 millions of records in totals) since I am setting up a Logical replication for some tables.

Currently, using this query :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pg_ls_dir('pg_wal') WHERE pg_ls_dir ~ '^[0-9A-F]{24}';
```

I find 6817 files. My goal is to reduce this number to just 10 - 20 files maximum.

1. How do this without affecting any other things such as restore etc ? Currently, the min WAL size is 1GB and the max is 4GB.
2. Suppose I just want 10 files. How to zip the rest 6807 files ?
3. If I want to do the whole process automatically, what do I have to do / set ?

I am using PG 12.11 running on Ubuntu 20.04

Thanks.
BTW, I am new to PG.

Comment: The only way to reduce the WAL size is to run fewer DML statements.

Comment: Ok. Nice. How can I safely reduce my existing WAL files then ?

Comment: Postgres will remove no longer needed WAL segments automatically until `min_wal_size` is reached. It might take a while though, but eventually they will be gone. **Never**, ever mess with the `pg_wal` directory manually. Never

Comment: I find some articles about archiving the wal files, like https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/115147/how-i-compact-wal-files and https://www.endpointdev.com/blog/2017/03/postgres-wal-files-best-compression/. How come ?

Comment: Check your `max_wal_size` setting, and reduce to be 80MB. That should do it. If not, then you might have problem with broken archiving, or old replication slots, or wal_keep_size, or prepared transactions. Hard to say.

For debugging I'd suggest you ask on irc/slack/discord, as it will more of a conversation than "here you go: do a, b, c".

Comment: Archiving is done by Postgres whenever a WAL segment is no longer needed. It's typically part of a complete backup strategy. It does _not_ qualify as "messing with pg_wal manually"

Answer (score 2):

WAL segments are not files that are kept around for ever. After they have been archived and are no longer necessary fro crash recovery, PostgreSQL automatically deletes them. You must never manually modify anything in `pg_wal` (or anywhere else in the data directory, with the exception of the configuration files), on pain of data corruption.

The correct way to reduce the amount of WAL would be to set `max_wal_size`, but note that small values can lead to increased write I/O, which is bad for performance.

All that said, there is something wrong with your database cluster. If you are using the default WAL segments size, you must have over 100GB of WAL. That is a clear indication that something is wrong. Either the archiver is not working (check `pg_stat_archiver`) or there is a stale replication slot that holds back WAL (check `pg_replication_slots`). Once you have fixed the problem, run `CHECKPOINT` (or wait for the next to happen by itself), and PostgreSQL will remove the extra WAL segments.

Yet another possibility is that you have `wal_keep_size` (`wal_keep_segments` on older versions) set to a very high value.

Comment: Hi @Laurenz Albe,

So I check :

--- `pg_stat_archiver` : **archived**_count 0, **failed_count** 0, **stats_reset** 30 June 2022.
--- `pg_replication_slots` : **catalog_xmin** 6954547, **restart_lsn** 96/2CCAD398, **confirmed_flush_lsn** 96/2CCAD3D0, **active** CHECKED. **plugin** PGOUTPUT, **slot_type** Logical, **slot_name** test_mysub, **active_pid** 1382293.
--- `checkpoint_timeout` : 300 s


What do I have to look ? What do I have to fix ?

Thanks